# Using Fused Location provider for android in a non activity java class and get longitude and latitude in main Activity class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I want to use fused location provider in my android application and get the current users location longitude and latitude and pass it as a map link in text message.
I used this example [FusedLocation Example](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html) to get **long** and **lat** coordinates of location but in my case i want to put all fusedLocation functions in a java class which is a non activity class and call it from main activity class to get **long** and **lat** ,

since i m a beginner in android and i searched alot to find something like this but couldn't get a example or tutorial.

can anybody help me in this or advice me if its the better solution to retrieve location coordinates and address from any provider working in any situations?
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Actually i want to use fused location Api in my android project in non activity java class and access location coordinates from main activity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite possible - in fact you can take a look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/40efa5a37849299dde64d6a397cbbb84) that I created. Essentially, the "non-Activity" class that you use, should implement the Location-Service Connection Listeners `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` ,`GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` (or receive instance of `GoogleApiClient` as parameter), and also the `LocationListener` -you may also want to pass the `Context` object to the constructor of that class (which will be the activity's context).
[Here is Gist](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/40efa5a37849299dde64d6a397cbbb84) which provides an example of implementing a `LocationListener`.

Comment: thank you for your answer , The examples looks very useful i got hint on how to implement it for my project , i think storing location coordinates in sharedPreferences are the best idea to access it anywhere , unfortunately i got too many errors after adding your java class in my project maybe it needs libraries

Comment: Hi, mine was just an example for you to get some ideas - but it was part of my bigger application and that's why it requires some libraries and other classes. In your case, simply implement the Listeners and callbacks - I will create another Gist and you can look at it and try it out.

Comment: As promised, here is [the updated Gist](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/40efa5a37849299dde64d6a397cbbb84) - in this Gist I am referencing a class called `LastKnownUserPosition` - [here is the Gist for this class](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/d64dc74e9e87e81701bd975f06cf0682) - this is not really necessary - but I am using it to create a JSON string representing current Lat and Lon and then storing into the SharedPreferences as a `String` - and then to convert from JSON-string to my Java class using Gson when reading from SharedPreference - I felt this made my life easy.

Comment: oh thank you very much i really appreciate your help and assistance , the problem is solved :)

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361131/how-to-find-the-distance-traveled-in-kilometers-by-following-gps-co-ordinates-us/40361297#40361297 can you look at this?